# How to develop an IE plugin that will execute within browser with <OBJECT> tags

Tags: c++, html, internet-explorer, plugins, embedding

I'm new to the realm of web/plugin development and I'm not sure what I need to be researching.

What I need is to develop a C++ app/dll/control/something that will install as a browser plugin and can be embedded and ran within IE when `<object>...</object>` tags call it (or any HTML tag that will embed something of the sort).  Exactly how Adobe Flash executes within a given space within an IE window.

I've searched and have seen and created a basic BHO, but that doesn't seem to be the functionality I need, or maybe I haven't looked deep enough into its abilities.

Any tips or pointers?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking to develop an ActiveX control here

[Using ActiveX Controls to Automate Your Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752037%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I looked into ActiveX, is there something extra you need to do to run ActiveX without the end users browser asking permission?  Like Flash, if you have it installed, it automatically plays a flash file within the browser without user interaction...

Comment: the first time you install flash, I think the browser asks you do you wish to run this plugin. There may be a way if you have local access to the machine to configure an activeX control to run without prompting, ie. find where IE saves the information on whats ok to run, and add your activeX to this list

Answer (score 0):

The term for browser plugins used by Microsoft is [Content Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741309%28VS.85%29.aspx). They are ActiveX based and allow you to add *alternative content* to a web-page as well as scriptable interfaces.

If there is a possibility that you'll need to support more than IE, consider using a wrapper like [FireBreath](http://firebreath.org) that allows you to support multiple browsers from one code-base.

Comment: Content Extensions, there's some new material to look into, thanks!